# Two way data flow on Vue component

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuex

I want a selector in a Vue component to update when the stored value in Vuex is updated. Here is a simplified version of the vue component:

```
<template>
    <v-autocomplete
      outlined
      dense
      v-model="team"
      label="Select Team"
      :items="teams"
      item-text="name"
      item-value="_id"
      return-object
      class="mx-3 mt-3"
      @change="selectTeam"
    ></v-autocomplete>
</template>
```

The JS:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'NavDrawer',
  data() {
    return {
      team: null,
      teams: [],
    };
  },
  async created() {
    this.team = this.$store.getters['teams/allTeams'].find(
      (t) => t.name === this.$route.params.team,
    );
    this.teams = this.$store.getters['teams/allTeams'];
  },
  methods: {
    async selectTeam() {
      if (this.team) {
        await this.$store.dispatch('editTeam/selectTeam', this.team);
        this.$router.push(`/team/${this.team.name}`);
      } else {
        this.$router.push('/');
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

And the Vuex store:

```
export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state: () => ({
    editedTeam: {},
  }),
  mutations: {
    selectTeam(state, team) {
      state.editedTeam = team;
    },
    resetTeam(state) {
      state.editedTeam = {};
    },
  },
  actions: {
    selectTeam({ commit }, team) {
      commit('selectTeam', team);
    },
    resetTeam({ commit }) {
      commit('resetTeam');
    },
  },
  getters: {
    getSelectedTeam: (state) => state.editedTeam,
  },
};
```

I'm not sure if it matters, but this vuex store is passed into an index file to create the Vuex.Store -- this is working correctly and is not the issue.

I want the team stored in editedTeam to reactively update the team selected in the v-autocomplete component, when a new editedTeam is selected elsewhere in the application. I want the v-autocomplete selector to send a new team to editedTeam when it is selected. I think I should be using mapState for this and storing them as a computed value -- but nothing I've tried has worked. I find the vuex documentation to be lacking in good examples.

Thanks!

Comment: Why does `dispatch` refer to the namespaced module as `editTeam` but the getters refer to it as `teams`?

Comment: I recommend creating a CodeSandbox, possibly a simplified version that still exhibits the problem.

Comment: @shob, thanks for the question -- they are two different stores. The one displayed above is the ```editTeam``` store. There's another store that holds all the teams -- that one is ```teams```

Comment: I see.  They should maybe all be in one module.  That aside, is this an overview component or no?  It shows all teams yet it expects a single team param.  And 2nd question, is this a parent route of the `/team` route it directs to?

Comment: I don't understand why it would matter if they were in the same module or separate modules, as they are both referenced via an index file that exports all the store's modules together. It might be worth a try to combine them, but I don't see why that would change anything. Currently, the component is referencing a parameter from the URL to look up the selected team from a list of all teams. The desired behavior is to reactively update the selected team based on a change to the editTeam/selectedTeam vuex state property.